# New apk uploaded and getting "Supported devices 0" on my developer console

Tags: android, release, device

Just uploaded 2 new apks and on both I'm getting supported devices 0.
Just looked around and I can't think of anything suspicious with my manifest.
Can someone shed some light on this?
thanks

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem when I published my app recently. If I recall correctly, I had to click on the APK tab and select the APK file (possibly by clicking an "Activate" button). I hope this helps you in the right direction. Since I already fixed it, I can't see the same options that you see.

Comment: Just checked and both apks are activated. Tried to deactivate and activate again and didn't work.

Comment: Does your AndroidManifest.xml file have a `<uses-sdk>` tag?

Comment: @bond I have to try to reproduce the problem with a valid APK file. I will get back with you later today or tomorrow when (if?) I figure it out.

Comment: Ok just managed to get it working. Seems the beta console doesn't activate the apk. Used the old design and was able to activate the apk and now shows about 1900 devices. thanks.

Comment: @bond I forgot to ask which version you were using. Glad to see you got it working.

Comment: Hello , i am facing same problem... I don't know what could be the issue as now i am not able to revert back to older version and there is no options to activate apk... As i checked i am getting one extra field in Dashboard that is : Native platform : junit-LICENSE.html , junit.jar , i dont know from where it comes but this could be the issue... can you guys can help out... please

Comment: @RakeshGondaliya Make sure your project is a standard project and not a test project.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem when I used commons.jar in build.gradle as follows:

```
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4
```

I solved it by doing this instead:

```
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
```

Alternatively one can manually download the library and put it in a libs folder, thus applying it as follows instead:

```
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
```

Comment: I wish somebody can explain the root cause and why this solves the problem.

Comment: this problem was driving me crazy. This libray sets the native platform of the APK to commons-io-2.4.jar